# Iterating through a directory and assigning each file a variable to work with

Tags: directory, spyder

I'm really new to Python, so in advance thank you for this probably stupid question:

I have a directory filled with LAS files and I would like to assign each of the with a variable, so that I can continue working with them all afterwards. I can't seem to find an answer that works ... the code below, is for some reason I cant figure out not working - thanks for the help!

## %%

```
### Importing function packages ### NumPy, Pandas, PyPlot, OS, LASio, Sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import lasio as las


#%%
#Directory
my_dir = os.walk("C:\\Users\\L_R\\Desktop\\test\\")
my_list = []

#Creates a list with LAS files in the DIR
for i in my_dir:
    my_list.append(i)
print my_list

#Iterates through DIR and creates dataframes out of files

count=0
current_las=my_list[count]
filename = current_las

for dirname, dirs, files in my_dir:
    while count < len(my_list):      
        if filename.endswith(".LAS"):
            las_output = las.read(filename) #module reading the file
        count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things. First I assume you have a dictionary, and you want to extract the items and assign them to variables using the names saved in the keys. Is that correct?

You could load the entire directory and then save them to the correct files.

If I am correct, this code will allow you first load the data and then save the data to variables.

```
D = np.load('Dict.py')

for key,val in D.items():
     exec(key + '=val')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Sorry, for not being as exact as I'm supposed to (still very new to this). I actually have a module (LASio) that reads my datafile and puts it into a dataframe - this works fine. However, I'm having trouble opening all the files (.LAS files) in a directory to run algorhythms over all of the LAS files.